# Fixing Typo in Javascript File in Github

Tags: javascript, github

I am very new to Github. I am trying to fix a typo in a Javascript file. I have created a separate branch, added the file but I'm not sure exactly how to amend the typo here. This just gives me an unrelated histories error and I'm just a bit confused about how to correct this file:

```
 // Constants
const PORT = 8001;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
 const app = express();
 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.send('Hello, Wrld');
 });

 app.listen(PORT, HOST);
 console.log(); '''
```

This is what I've done so far.

to say "Hello World" instead of "Hello, World"

```
     git branch fix_typo
     git checkout fix_typo
     git add server.js
     cat server.js
     echo “Hello, World” > server.j
     git add server.js
     git commit --amend -m "Hello, World Fix Typo"
     git checkout master
     git merge fix_typo
     git push origin fix_typo
```

I also wanted to ask how would I go about changing the port on this file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the file to the new branch. When you make a branch, it copies all the files from the current branch.

You shouldn't just `echo "Hello, World"` to the file, you need to edit the file to keep all the other lines. You can use `sed` for this, and you can use multiple `-e` options to perform multiple substitutions.

```
git branch fix_typo
git checkout fix_typo
sed -i -e 's/Hello, Wrld/Hello, World/' -e 's/PORT = 8001/PORT = 80/' server.js
git commit -m "Hello, World Fix Typo"
git push
git checkout master
git merge fix_typo
git push origin
```

Comment: Thanks so much this is great! Could I also ask your advice on changing the port please?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do that.